# jcmd doesn't produce output for VM.native_memory

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to analyze native memory for possible memory leaks using `jmcd` command.

The application is ran with the following VM args:

```
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary
```

Using `jps` to get the process pid:

```
sudo ./jps -l
25125 MyService
```

However `jcmd`  command fails:

```
sudo ./jcmd 25125 VM.native_memory
25125:
java.io.IOException: well-known file /tmp/.java_pid25125 is not secure: file should be owned by the current user (which is 0) but is owned by 37561
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.checkPermissions(Native Method)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:117)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
    at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.executeCommandForPid(JCmd.java:147)
    at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.main(JCmd.java:131)
sudo ./jcmd -F 25125 VM.native_memory
Invalid pid specified
```

P.S. Using `openjdk-8`:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_362-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.362-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Try to invoke it with the same user as MyService is running under via `sudo -u theuser jcmd ...`